# Javascript form submit change action with attr attributes

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms

I want to change the attribute action from my form in the goal to get the next page dynamically. In javascript, my variable `action` get the right 'value' but the page does not load still. It works fine if I return manually the right 'value', but it does not work when I use `jQuery('#select_program').children().filter(':selected').text().replace(/\s+/g, '-').toLowerCase(),` to make it dynamically.

Here is my form (in php):

```
public function form_creation() {
    $html = '<form id="search_projects" action="';
    $html .= esc_url(get_bloginfo('url'));
    $html .= '/" method="post">';
        $html .= '<select id="select_langue" name="lg123" onchange="change_select(0, this.value)">';
            $html .= '<option value="nd" class="optionDefault">';
                $html .= __('Language', 'mon-plugin'); 
                $html .= '</option>';
        $html .= '</select>';
        $html .= '<select id="select_program" name="pg123" onchange="change_select(1, this.value)">';
            $html .= '<option value="nd" class="optionDefault">';
                $html .= __('Program', 'mon-plugin');
            $html .= '</option>';
        $html .= '</select>';
        $html .= '<select id="select_country" name="dst123" onchange="change_select(2, this.value)">';
            $html .= '<option value="nd" class="optionDefault">';
                $html .= __('Country', 'mon-plugin');
            $html .= '</option>';
        $html .= '</select>';
        $html .= '<select id="select_city" name="city123" onchange="change_select(3, this.value)">';
            $html .= '<option value="nd" class="optionDefault">';
                $html .= __('City', 'mon-plugin');
            $html .= '</option>';
        $html .= '</select>';
        $html .= '<input type="hidden" name="data123" value="';
        $html .= htmlspecialchars(json_encode($this->backend_select_category));
        $html .= '"/>';
        $html .= '<button id="submit_project_list" type="submit">';
            $html .= '<i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i>';
            $html .= __('Search', 'mon-plugin');
        $html .= '</button>';
    $html .= '</form>';

    return $html;
}
```

Here is my javascript:

```
jQuery('#search_projects').submit(function() {
    var selection_value = [
        jQuery('#select_langue').val(),
        jQuery('#select_program').val(),
        jQuery('#select_country').val(),
        jQuery('#select_city').val()
    ];
    var selection_display = [
        jQuery('#select_langue').children().filter(':selected').text().replace(/\s+/g, '-').toLowerCase(),
        jQuery('#select_program').children().filter(':selected').text().replace(/\s+/g, '-').toLowerCase(),
        jQuery('#select_country').children().filter(':selected').text().replace(/\s+/g, '-').toLowerCase(),
        jQuery('#select_city').children().filter(':selected').text().replace(/\s+/g, '-').toLowerCase()
    ];
    jQuery(this).attr('action', function() {
        if (selection_value[1] !== 'nd') {
            var action = selection_display[1];
            if (selection_value[2] !== 'nd') {
                action += selection_display[2];
                if (selection_value[3] !== 'nd') {
                    action += selection_display[3];
                }
            }
        } else {
            var action = 'search_program';
        }
        return action;
    });
});
```

Thank you for your help !

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem.

I realize when I do not change any select, the page changes like it should. But when I change just one select, the page does not load anymore.

I don't know why, but the problem comes from my **hidden input** in php. If I remove it, everything works.

Great.. but how can I send my data through this form to the other page so ?

Thank you in advance for your help !